# How to delete list elements based on condition in Python

Tags: python, list

I have following 2D array in python

```
[[(0, 0, 0), 337.94174378689814],
[(0, 0, 1), 339.92776762374007],
[(0, 0, 2), 338.78632729456444],
[(0, 1, 0), 344.85997106879347],
[(0, 1, 1), 331.6819890120493],
[0, 0]]
```

I want to delete elements which has 0 values in it 
The output is `ARIMA order and corresponding AIC score` which I generate from following code

```
a = [[0]*2 for x in range(27)]

for i in range(len(pdq)):
   try:
      mod =  ARIMA(train, order = pdq[i]) 
      results = mod.fit(disp=False)
      a[i][0] = pdq[i]
      a[i][1] = results.aic
      if a[i][1] == 0:
         a.remove(a[i])
   except:
       continue
```

I want to delete values in array where there are both `0`. How can I do it in `if condition described above`

Comment: Do you want to delete the last [0,0] only?

Comment: Yes, wherever there is [0,0] we should delete it

Comment: Array or list? There's a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to delete [0,0] you can do it like this:

```
a = [[(0, 0, 0), 337.94174378689814],
     [(0, 0, 1), 339.92776762374007],
     [(0, 0, 2), 338.78632729456444],
     [(0, 1, 0), 344.85997106879347],
     [(0, 1, 1), 331.6819890120493],
     [0, 0]]

while True:
    try:
        a.remove([0, 0])
    except ValueError:
        break
```

Or use filter:

```
a = list(filter(lambda x: x != [0, 0], a))
```

Comment: @jpp remove until there is no [0,0] in list

Comment: I believe this will have O(m*n) complexity. It has to pass the list multiple times to get all of them.

Comment: @jpp Yeah, slow

Comment: Then how do I get minimum AIC score index from above?

Comment: let's say minimum AIC score is `331.68` then how do I fetch a[4]

Comment: @Neil, that's a separate question, I suggest you ask a new one.

Answer (score 18):

I assume you have a regular Python `list`, not a NumPy `np.ndarray`.

It's tempting to think that an in-place solution will be more efficient than creating a new list. This isn't really the case, O(n) complexity can't be beaten as you'll need to check each element at least once.

So you can use a list comprehension for this:

```
res = [i for i in L if i != [0, 0]]
```

Indeed, repeated `list.remove` calls will be inefficient: *each* `list.remove` call has O(n) [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Answer (score 6):

With

```
>>> elements = [[(0, 0, 0), 337.94174378689814],
                [(0, 0, 1), 339.92776762374007],
                [(0, 0, 2), 338.78632729456444],
                [(0, 1, 0), 344.85997106879347],
                [(0, 1, 1), 331.6819890120493],
                [0, 0]]
```

we can write a `list` comprehension

```
>>> [element for element in elements if element != [0,0]]
```

or (IMO more readable) with predicate

```
def is_valid(element):
    return element != [0, 0]
```

we can use [`filter` built-in](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) like

```
# wrapping in ``list`` because in Python3 ``filter`` returns iterator
>>> list(filter(is_valid, elements))  
[[(0, 0, 0), 337.94174378689814], 
 [(0, 0, 1), 339.92776762374007],
 [(0, 0, 2), 338.78632729456444], 
 [(0, 1, 0), 344.85997106879347],
 [(0, 1, 1), 331.6819890120493]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach that would give the same result would be to filter the list and create a new one:

```
a = [e for e in a if any(e)]
```

You could also use the built in `filter` function:

```
a = list(filter(any, a))
```

This saves you from shifting all the elements over every time you delete one from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Solution when needing to delete a list within a list (i.e. list of lists) based on condition of an element. Here we delete any list if any element is a NaN. Using e == e to test for NaN. lofl is the list of lists.

```
newlofl = [l for l in lofl if all(e == e for e in l)]
```

Anyone have a faster, better method for this situation?

Answer (score -1):

```
m = [[(0, 0, 0), 337.94174378689814],
     [(0, 0, 1), 339.92776762374007],
     [(0, 0, 2), 338.78632729456444],
     [(0, 1, 0), 344.85997106879347],
     [(0, 1, 1), 331.6819890120493],
     [0, 0]]

for r in m:
    if [0,0] in r:
        m.remove(r)
```